# Gecoding Colloquial Place Names: Zero Results, but Can Get Manual Results (R ggmap)

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, geocoding, ggmap

I'd like to know the latitudes and longitudes of the district offices on the island of Java, Indonesia. Districts are administrative regions, like states in the USA. Most of my geocode queries return inaccurate results: the latitude and longitude are for the district as a whole, not the district office. Yet if I type the query into Google Maps manually, I find what I want.

```
library("ggmap")
# list of district names
dists <- read.csv("../javaDistNames.csv")
# vector of queries for Google maps
queries <- paste("Kantor Bupati ", dists$distName, ", ", dists$distName, 
           ", ", dists$provinceName, ", Indonesia", sep="")
# impute latitude and longitude
dists[c("lon", "lat")] <- geocode(queries)
```

The expression "Kantor Bupati" means District Office in Indonesian.

E.g., if I type "Kantor Bupati BOGOR, BOGOR, JAWA BARAT, Indonesia" into google maps, I find the [district office](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kantor+Bupati+Bogor/@-6.4797348,106.8225483,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x2e69c1eb55439883:0x20408578e9d2a9d!8m2!3d-6.4797348!4d106.8247424): lat=-6.479745, lon=106.824742. But geocode [returns](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bogor,+Bogor+City,+West+Java,+Indonesia/@-6.6100866,106.7906541,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x2e69c44a0cd6aab5:0x301576d14feb9a0!8m2!3d-6.5971469!4d106.8060388): lat=-6.597147, lon=106.806. That is 20km away: not precise enough for my purposes.

Comment: I think it's because Google Maps uses [Google Places](https://developers.google.com/places/), whereas 'geocode' uses [Google Geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). I have a `google_places()` function in the development version of my [googleway](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package - but I can't get it to work with your query either. You're welcome to try if you're happy working with dev packages.

Comment: Thanks. I can't get `google_places()` to work either, but good to know why there is a difference.

Comment: Just a note about Geocoding API vs. Google Maps search. They're not quite the same, even for non-business results. This tool uses only Geocoding API (if you hit Enter without clicking on suggestions): https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DKantor%2520Bupati%2520BOGOR%252C%2520BOGOR%252C%2520JAWA%2520BARAT%252C%2520Indonesia

Comment: I've updated `googleway` development, and in particular the `google_places()` function and I now think it's returning the correct data: `google_places(key = key, search_string = "Kantor Bupati BOGOR, BOGOR, JAWA BARAT, Indoneia")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this: I use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) as SymbolixAU suggested. The vectorized function below takes as arguments the colloquial place names we want to geocode and a second vector of non-colloquial place names that can be geocoded using `ggmap`'s `geocode`. It returns latitude, longitude, and the name of the place. Get an API key [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/).

```
library("ggmap") # regular geocode function
library("RJSONIO") # read JSON

# API Key for Google Places
key <- # your key here

geoCodeColloquial <- function(queries, bases) {

  # need coordinates of base to focus search
  print("Getting coordinates of bases...")
  baseCoords <- geocode(bases, source="google")

  # request to Google Places
  print("Requesting coordinates of queries...")
  requests <- paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=",
                   baseCoords$lat, ",", baseCoords$lon, 
                   "&radius=50000&keyword=",
                   queries,
                   "&key=",
                   key,
                   sep="")

  # results from Google Places; take only top result for each query
  info <- lapply(requests, 
                   function(request) 
                     fromJSON(request)$results[[1]])

  # lat and lon
  coords <- lapply(info, function(i) i$geometry$location)

  # name of top result
  geoCodeNames <- lapply(info, function(i) i$name)
  geoCodeNamesDf <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(geoCodeNames),
                                      nrow=length(geoCodeNames), byrow=T))

  # add lat, lon, and discovered names to dataframe
  outDf <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(coords),
                                nrow=length(coords), byrow=T))
  names(outDf) <- c("lat", "lon")
  outDf["geoCodeName"] <- geoCodeNamesDf
  return(outDf)
}
```